# How to display the text with "anchor tag", coming from json response in react?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, anchor

I have the following code:

JSON Response:

```
{
   "url": ["http://google.com"],
   "text": ["Click <a>me</a> for help"]
}
```

Code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

export const Print = (props) => (
  <Fragment>
    {(props.text[0].split('/n').length && props.text[0].split('/n').map(i => {
      return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: i }}></p>
    })) || text[0]}
  </Fragment>
)
```

**My Requirement**:

```
<p> Click <a href="http://google.com">me</a> for help <p>
```

This should work like above. I'm unable to understand how to render json, so that dangerouslySetInnerHTML will take anchor tag from "**url**" in response and assign it to **i** in code.

The code will be in a different file. This file will be called from a different file, and JSON response will be sent to this file as prop.

Comment: Are you asking how to split that string into `["Click ", "<a>me</a>", " for help"]`? Are you trying to assign the URL as the anchor tag's `href`? Please always ask about your actual problem, not about the solution you think will solve it but might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only suitable for your specific case. It ignores several `<a>` tags and only works with clean `<a>` tags, not `<a class="whatever">`. Also, be careful with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, it’s [easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
const response = {
  "url": ["http://google.com", "http://example.com"],
  "text": ["Click <a>me</a> for help", "And <a>me</a> for test"]
};

export default function App() {
  const els = response.text.map((text, i) => text.replace("<a>", `<a href=${response.url[i]}>`));

  return (
    <>
      {els.map((el, i) => <p key={i} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: el }} />)}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-kare-gdb1k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What if it's `<a class="whatever">` in that piece of HTML?

Comment: @ChrisG There are many problems that still need to be solved, for example XSS attack and a few tags `<a>`, I just answered a specific question OP